# Как правильно добавлять данные в 1 коллекцию из разных потоков?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня в классе `Main` есть коллекция

```
public  ObservableList<NewsData> listNews = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

и есть несколько потоков, которые добавляют данные в эту коллекцию, как правильно организовать доступ к коллекции из разных потоков?
На данный момент я сделал коллекцию `static` и просто в каждом потоке добавляю данные

```
listNews.add(newsData);
```

но подозреваю что это не самый лучший вариант

Comment: А что мешает добавлять данные в одном потоке(например в основном)? Создать метод и в него передавать параметры с других потоков?

Comment: Есть специальные структуры данных для работы с многопоточностью (из Java Concurrent Collection) - типа CopyOnWriteArrayList, ConcurrentHashMap и т.д. Возможно, Вам стоит присмотреть к ним. static обычно не самое лучшее решение для работы с многопоточностью...

Comment: "А что мешает добавлять данные в одном потоке(например в основном)? Создать метод и в него передавать параметры с других потоков?" - вот я сейчас ищу как это правильно сделать...в классе Мейн создаю синхронизированный метод, но что бы видеть этот метод из других потоков его нужно сделать статическим (и значит саму коллекцию тоже статической) или в каждом потоке создавать экземпляр класса Мейн, не знаю насколько это правильно...Просто я только начинаю изучать java  по этому вопросы такие банальные...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потокобезопасным вариантом ObservableList является SynchronizedObservableList, используйте его.
[Подробнее здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.SynchronizedObservableList.html)

Comment: спасибо сейчас почитаю как его использовать

Comment: Его еще можно как обертку над обычным ObservableList использовать.

Comment: как это выглядит в коде?

Comment: Через конструктор:
SynchronizedObservableList(ObservableList list) {}

Comment: ' public static ObservableList<NewsData> listNews = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static SynchronizedObservableList listNews = new SynchronizedObservableList(listNews) {} ;' у меня так не работает...

Comment: public static ObservableList<NewsData> listNews = FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableArrayList());    - так правильно записал?

Comment: Да, это ближе к правде, но нужно проверять.

Comment: попробовал у себя, работает...меня смущает что коллекция объявлена static

Comment: Можно использовать Singleton, я бы рассматривал такой вариант в первую очередь. В этом случае коллекцию стоит объявить как private final (без static). Подробнее - https://habr.com/post/129494/

Comment: отлично это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

пока что сделал как советовал  LaNC1LoT , в классе Maim создал синхронизированный метод

```
public synchronized static void addListNews(NewsData newsData) {listNews.add(newsData);}
```

а в потоках вызываю этот метод

```
mainParse.addListNews (newsData );
```

то что советует Igor Konyaev

```
 public static ObservableList<NewsData> listNews = FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
```

Answer (score 0):

как я сделал что бы не объявлять коллекцию как 'static' .
я создал отдельный класс где создаю свой список уже не статик и с модификатором доступа приват и прописываю метод который добавляет в коллекцию элементы и которые передает по ссылке сам список кому нужно (мне нужно что бы отображать данные в таблице TableView

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ListNews {
private  ObservableList<NewsData> listNews = 
FXCollections.synchronizedObservableList(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

// для потоков которые добавляют данные
public synchronized void addListNews (NewsData newsData){
    listNews.add(newsData);
}
// для таблицы TableView которорая отображает данные
public ObservableList getListNews (){
    return listNews;
} 
}
```

в самом классе мейн я создал экземпляр класса ListNews:

```
ListNews listNews = new ListNews();
```

listNews передаю в потоки по ссылке в конструкторе и в самом потоке добавляю данные через метод

```
listNews.addListNews (newsData );
```

все оказывается банально просто, сложно только когда делаешь первый раз.